# Unable to understand the navigation in jitsi

Tags: reactjs, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I want to make a conferencing app using Jitsi and add some of my own pages in it. Is it possible to navigate between my pages and jitsi conferencing page.

I've tried to understand the code and flow in the lib-jitsi-meet repository. Here's the github link https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a custom UI for the conferencing piece, a good idea (and easier) would be to use Jitsi Meet External API to embed conferencing in your application

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi provides two types of API documentation.

1. iFrame API:- You can easily add Jitsi as an Iframe.
2. lib-jitsi-meet : This will help for low-level development 
   For more details :-

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-ljm-api